# Converting an Array of Arrays into an Array of Strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, string

I currently have an array of arrays. There are 10 single-item arrays in my overall array

[["http://instagr.am/r/123"],["http://instagr.am/r/456"]....]

My goal is to clean this up so that it is an array of *strings*.

Ex:

[http://instagr.am/r/123, http://instagr.am/r/456, ... ]

I have been racking Google trying to find a solution for this but I seem to be unable to find one and I was hoping that you kind folks could help out an emerging Rubyist.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[`Array#flatten`](http://corelib.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#M000456)

```
[["http://instagr.am/r/123"],["http://instagr.am/r/456"]....].flatten
```

Answer (score 2):

```
array.map(&:first)
```

...............